# How to navigate back in view again in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, back, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have 2 screens about that I have passed the context and get the context in a method. just like this

```
stock_picking_obj=self.env['stock.picking']
context = dict(self._context) or {}
context.update({'is_first_picking_open':True})
stock_picking_obj.with_context(context)
```

When I receive context in the method.

```
@api.multi
def button_validate(self):
    context=dict(self._context)
    if context.get('is_first_picking_open'):
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'tag': 'history_back'}
```

so basically I want to once a process has been that after coming back with the old screen.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you update the context in recent versions of Odoo.

First of all the context exists on the Environment and you can fetch it like this:
`self.env.context` and it will always be a dictionary so there is no reason for `dict() or {}`

Now, the `with_context` function returns the recordset you call it upon with the context changed. Example:

`stock_pickings = stock_pickings.with_context(context)`

and then you can

`stock_pickings.button_validate()` and you will be able to fetch the context by using `self.env.context`